# How to set a full date with MomentJS using only the name for the month?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to know if MomentJS have any option to set a full date like `"2019-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"` using a string name for month like `Mar`

What I am trying to do is to get the transactions for the selected month like this. But this is working only for the current month;

```
const month = moment.utc();  // here I would use something to define the selected month
const startMonth = moment(month).startOf("month");
const endMonth = moment(month).endOf("month");
const monthTransaction = getUserTransactions.filter(
  transaction =>
    transaction.createdAt > startMonth.toISOString() &&
    transaction.createdAt < endMonth.toISOString()
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the month name you can do something like this to parse it to moment date:

```
moment("Mar", "MMM")
```

See here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/ for more info about parsing options.

Comment: `const monthsArray = moment.monthsShort();
      const dates = monthsArray.map(month => {
        return moment(month, "MMM");
      });
      console.log(dates);` using this way its missing October and is showing the first day of march and last day of march

Comment: sounds strange, maybe because of timezone/utc configuration, what does it output when you run this:

```const monthsArray = moment.monthsShort();
const dates = monthsArray.map(month => moment(month, "MMM").toISOString(true));```